# $(A^{-1}+B^{-1})^{-1}=A-A(A+B)^{-1}A$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A, B$ and $A+B$ be invertible matrices. Show that
> $(A^{-1}+B^{-1})^{-1}=A-A(A+B)^{-1}A$

Here's my assumption:

\begin{align}
A^{-1} + B^{-1} &= B^{-1} + A^{-1} \\
&= B^{-1}(A + B)A^{-1} \\
\end{align}
Then

\begin{align}
(A^{-1} + B^{-1})^{-1} &= [B^{-1}(A + B)A^{-1}]^{-1} \\
&=A(A+B)^{-1}B
\end{align}

\begin{align}
(A^{-1} + B^{-1})^{-1}B^{-1} &= A(A+B)^{-1}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
-(A^{-1} + B^{-1})^{-1}B^{-1}A &=- A(A+B)^{-1}A
\end{align}
\begin{align}
A-(A^{-1} + B^{-1})^{-1}B^{-1} A&=A- A(A+B)^{-1}A
\end{align}

But I'm stuck. I would be very appreciate if someone could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $(A^{-1}+B^{-1})^{-1}=A(A+B)^{-1}B$, you get

$A(A+B)^{-1}B=A(A+B)^{-1}(B+A-A)=A-A(A+B)^{-1}A$

**Note:** Besides invertibility of $A$ and $B$, you may need to add the assumption that $(A+B)$ is invertible too. From that, following your reasoning, it follows that  $(A^{-1}+B^{-1})$ is invertible.

Comment: Unrelated but I want to ask this. Do we have a formula about the inverse of the sum of the matrices?

Comment: Not in general. However, if one has a norm on $M_n(A)$ such that $\|A B\|\leq \|A\|\|B\|$ and $\|I\|=1$ (there are many is such norms) and $\|A\|<1$, then $$(I-A)^{-1}=\sum^\infty_{n=0}A^k$$

Comment: I don't now if this is more helpful or not, but it is a representation of $(I-A)^{-1}$ in terms of powers of $A$.

Comment: Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$
A = A(A+B)^{-1}(A+B)
$$